# Evaluating an Antiderivative to Two Different Functions

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have recently been struggling with finding the antiderivative of the rational function $$\int \frac{1}{x \cdot \ln(x^3)}dx$$

I am only recently in calculus, so I expect to have made a basic mistake, which I would like to understand.
Initially, when I tried to evaluate this problem, I used the logarithmic power property to rewrite the integrand as $\frac{1}{3 \cdot x \cdot \ln(x)}$

When substituting $u = \ln(x)$ and $du = \frac{1}{x}dx$, I rewrote the problem as $\int\frac{du}{3 \cdot u}$. Factoring out the $\frac{1}{3}$, I then got $\frac{1}{3} \cdot \int \frac{du}{u}$, which I evaluated to $\frac{\ln|u|}{3} + C$, or $$\frac{\ln|\ln(x)|}{3} + C$$

However, when I attempted to re-do the problem in a different way (without simplifying $\ln(x^3)$), I substituted $u = ln(x^3)$ and $du = \frac{3x^2dx}{x^3}$, which I simplified to $\frac{3dx}{x}$. When performing the substitution, I wound up with $\int\frac{du}{3 \cdot u}$, and, when factoring out the constant, I am left with $\frac{1}{3} \cdot \int\frac{du}{u}$, which I found the antiderivative to be $\frac{1}{3} \cdot \ln|u| + C$, and, with a final substitution of $u$, I am left with $$\frac{\ln|\ln(x^3)|}{3} + C$$

I am struggling to understand how these functions would have the same derivative (assuming I did found the antiderivative correctly both times), as one has $x^3$ and one simply has $x$. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your answers are correct; they just differ by a constant.

$$\frac{\ln|\ln(x^3)|}{3}+C$$

$$=\frac{\ln|3\ln(x)|}{3}+C$$

$$=\frac{\ln3 + \ln|\ln(x)|}{3}+C$$

$$=\frac{\ln|\ln(x)|}{3}+\frac{\ln3}{3}+C$$

This $\frac{\ln3}{3}$ constant can be combined with the constant $C$ to produce a new constant $C'$

This makes the indefinite integral equal to

$$\frac{\ln|\ln(x)|}{3}+C'$$

which is the same thing as

$$\frac{\ln|\ln(x)|}{3}+C$$

because $C$ and $C'$ are arbitrary constants anyway